# Present perfect and present perfect continuous

Tags: difference, perfect-constructions

Someone has eaten all the cookies.

Someone has been eating all the cookies.

What is the difference in the two tenses?

Comment: In this case, by including the word "all," you've removed much of the difference in meaning, but this has nothing to do with the tense.

Answer (score 1):

Including the word "all" has complicated the meaning here, but it has nothing to do with the two tenses. Consider what the sentences would be like without it:

- "Someone has *eaten* the cookies": would usually suggest that the cookies have been entirely eaten.
- "Someone has *been eating* the cookies": would usually suggest simply that we see evidence that some eating has been happening. Does not necessarily mean that *all* the cookies have been eaten.

By adding the word "all"—*Someone has been eating all the cookies*—you force the first meaning onto the second. In fact, it becomes a bit nonsensical (though one could imagine it being said, especially as a whimsical tone).

One *could* imagine a different example, though, in which combining "all" with present perfect continuous brings a new meaning.

- "Something has eaten all the rats that have this gene!" —Means that no rats with the gene have survived.
- "Something has been eating all the rats that have this gene!" —Means that something has been finding many rats, but has only eaten "all" of them *that have the gene*.

Why does this work but "has been eating all the cookies" sounds odd? Mainly because this new example adds a descriptive modifier. If we said "Someone has been eating all the cookies that have nuts," it would be more plausible.

Answer (score 0):

**Someone has eaten all the cookies.**

This action is past in terms of the present but **we don't know when in the past** as we speak now. Just that it began at some undefined period

Compare: **Someone ate** all the cookies [yesterday].

Someone **has been eating the cookies**.

This action **began** sometime in the past and **was continuous in the past up to the time of speaking**. **The emphasis is on the action**, unlike the present perfect which just tell us that the action was in an undefined past.

[I removed all from the continuous as it just doesn't make much sense.]

Answer (score 0):

Someone has eaten all the cookies.- present perfect tense

Someone has been eating all the cookies.-present perfect continuous/progressive tense

The present **perfect** tense lays emphasis on the **result** of the activity.

The present **perfect continuous** tense puts emphasis on the **activity**. It does not matter whether the action has been finished or not.